# Docker layers, not pulling foreign layers for image in artifactory, there URL has changed?

Tags: docker, artifactory

We have push an update docker image to Artifactory

The two foreign layers used to look like this in the manfafest

```
 {
                "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.foreign.diff.tar.gzip",
                "size": 1718332879,
                "digest": "sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f",
                "urls": [
                        "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/servercore/blobs/sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f"
                ]
        },
        {
                "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.foreign.diff.tar.gzip",
                "size": 997587446,
                "digest": "sha256:ba8181afd4264392fbbf8df14fb4cddc55fbe085ab000e986b789678bc2bb171",
                "urls": [
                        "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/servercore/blobs/sha256:ba8181afd4264392fbbf8df14fb4cddc55fbe085ab000e986b789678bc2bb171"
                ]
      },
```

Now in the new image manfafest they look like this?

```
{
                    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.foreign.diff.tar.gzip",
                    "size": 1718332879,
                    "digest": "sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f",
                    "urls": [
                            "https://docker.securethingz.com:443/artifactory/api/docker/stz-docker/v2/stz/ltsc2019/mingw64build/blobs/sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f"
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.foreign.diff.tar.gzip",
                    "size": 997587446,
                    "digest": "sha256:ba8181afd4264392fbbf8df14fb4cddc55fbe085ab000e986b789678bc2bb171",
                    "urls": [
                            "https://docker.securethingz.com:443/artifactory/api/docker/stz-docker/v2/stz/ltsc2019/mingw64build/blobs/sha256:ba8181afd4264392fbbf8df14fb4cddc55fbe085ab000e986b789678bc2bb171"
                    ]
            },
```

And when i pull the new image all the layes come down except the two foreign layers it retries these layers lots and then fails :-(
The old image still pulls down fine.

if i goto the link diectry
*https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/servercore/blobs/sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f*
it downloads a file.
if i goto
*https://docker.securethingz.com:443/artifactory/api/docker/stz-docker/v2/stz/ltsc2019/mingw64build/blobs/sha256:4612f6d0b889cad0ed0292fae3a0b0c8a9e49aff6dea8eb049b2386d9b07986f*
it get this.
*{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}*

From what i can tell every thing in Arty is setup to be readble anonymously.

We are using *Arty 7.41.7 rev 74107900*

What up, and how can we fix this?

Comment: Foreign layers are always pulled directly from the upstream URL (they don't get pushed to your registry). So you need to verify access to that remote server.

Answer (score 1):

We have managed to resolve this. What we did :

Clean docker with docker system prune -a
We made a new simple docker file

```
FROM my_arty.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.2-20220913-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 
RUN echo "Done"
```

Build it and push it to my_arty
Now the other new images we had previously made are able to download on other machines.

Our assumption is that some layers from the remote repo got removed (we don't know how), and building and pushing the simple docker file re-primed them in the remote cache for mcr.microsoft.com on my_arty,  Restoring the integrity of all the manifests.

The *{*"errors":[
{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}
]}** when directly goto to the blob URL persists, but it would seem that was never really an issue.